# Class does not exist. | Silex Framework

Tags: framework, php, silex

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой "Class does not exist."
Структура:

```
/root
.../app
....../pages
.........MainController.php
.........SecondController.php
......app.php
...router.php
```

Содержание:
//router.php

```
$app->get('/', 'app\\pages\\MainController::main')->bind('main');
$app->get('/404', 'app\\pages\\SecondController::about')->bind('about');
return $app;
```

//MainController.php

```
namespace app\pages;
use Silex\Application;

class MainController {
  public function main (Application $app)
   return $app['twig']->render('main.html');
   }
}
```

//SecondController.php

```
namespace app\pages;
use Silex\Application;

class SecondController {
    public function about (Application $app) {
        return $app['twig']->render('about.html');
    }
```

//composer.json (cюда скопировал только секцию autoload)
    {
     "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
           "app": "./"
        }
     }
    }

Вот что интересно: MainController работает, а SecondController выдает "Class "app\pages\SecondController" does not exist.

Помогите, люди... Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Посмотрите, что в файлах `vendor/composer/autoload_*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, проблема решена: писав сюда, я классы переименовал. У меня же был класс с  _ , что недопустимо.
И надо бы рестарты делать.

P.S. Может кому и полезен пост будет)